# SimpleCursorAdapter срабатывает неправильно

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, cursoradaper

Нужно вывести из БД в строку `listView` два поля status и title. Проблема в том, когда я указываю в `SimpleCursorAdapter` эти поля приложение вылетает. Хотя если указать поля _id и title - всё срабатывает как надо. В чем ошибка? Кусок кода ниже:

```
String[] lines = new String[] {"title", "place"};
        cursor = mDB.query("requests", lines,  "id_ins = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(user)}, null, null, null);
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, cursor, lines, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

Кстати, если ли способ не создавать локальную переменную lines и через query указать данные на вывод?

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, текст ошибки из LogCat

Comment: Видимо вот те самые строки:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.myapp/InspectorPackage.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [title, status]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [title, status]

Comment: Вообще, эта ошибка говорит, что поле с именем '_id' не существует в БД, а Вы попытались к нему обратиться. Так же здесь сказано, что существуют только поля 'title' и 'status'

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код инициализации БД, значения строковых ресурсов

Comment: Поставил три поля в "lines" (последним "_id"), а на вывод которые мне нужны - "tutle" и "status" - всё отработало как нужно. Может адаптеру обязательно передавать поле "_id"? Даже если без отображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ в соседней теме.

> Так же колонка _id обязательно должна быть включена в выборку курсора.

Но выводить её в listview не обязательно.